# how to get json data in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been trying to fetch json data from my flutter app. I managed to print the whole json on my console. I want to get only the "text" value from this json. How should I do it?
here is the json link: [a link](http://motyar.info/webscrapemaster/api/?url=http://teertoday.com/&xpath=/html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]#vws)
I want to get only the number 54 from the json api
I get the output as:
[image]

```
Future<String> fetchData ()async{
    var response1 = await get("http://motyar.info/webscrapemaster/api/?url=http://teertoday.com/&xpath=/html/body/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]#vws");
    List teerModel =  json.decode(response1.body);
    print(teerModel[0]);

  }
```

Comment: to get 54 => teerModel[0]['text'], but your full value is different than usual, do you want it as integer?

Comment: @mathronaut  yes I want to get the value as an integer

Comment: @mathronaut i got it thanks for your help  i  spend for 10 hours only to get the number.

Comment: How did you achieve it?

Comment: @mathronaut  firstly I make a variable and converted it to string from there I just converted it to  int.